# https connection doesn't close java EE

Tags: jakarta-ee, https

Hello I am developoing a Java EE project where I want to have https connection at registration pages. I configured it by editing the server.xml file accordingly to tutorials I found and it works fine. My problem is that it won't close. If I open a page where https is triggered then all pages opened after this will be https instead of http? Is that the normal way https is behaved or I am doing something wrong?

Heres's the  content related from server.xml:

```
 <Connector SSLEnabled="true" clientAuth="false" keystoreFile="c:\Users\Mario\.keystore" keystorePass="123456" maxThreads="150" port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="https" secure="true" sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

and here is my web.xml of the project

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>Viewpoint Secure URLs</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/user/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
      <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
  </security-constraint>
  <servlet>
```

The pages under the "user" directory are opened with https but then every other page of the project is opened by https even the index.xhtml which is located a level above the user folder.

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/annotation/ServletSecurity.TransportGuarantee.html#CONFIDENTIAL):

> `ServletSecurity.TransportGuarantee CONFIDENTIAL`
>
> All user data must be
>   encrypted by the transport (typically using SSL/TLS).

It might be the case that the server sets the `Strict-Transport-Security` header to enforce the "all user data" constraint.

Comment: yeah, but this rule should be applied only to the pages under user not to the whole project. Or I don't get something?

Comment: The `Strict-Transport-Security` header works for the whole domain.